# Can I got hacked when I use an online youtube downloader

Tags: malware

Title says all. If I use online youtube downloader, is there any risk of putting my computer into danger? Like the video / audio file can contain dangerous executable code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You don't get "hacked". Don't use that word: it doesn't mean what lots of people think it means. The computer and security software assume you know what you're doing and don't inspect, or just allow, things you manually install yourself. So yes, if you tell your computer to install something that contains malicious code you will get "infected" (that's the right word). Only install software that comes from places and developers you have reason to trust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially. Or they could be fishing for personal information, or any number of other nefarious intents.

Or they could just be out to make ad rev off you with popups, etc...

But there's no need to risk such potential threats/annoyances - just use youtube-dl (https://github.com/ytdl-org) - there's plenty of tutorials out there on how to use it.